# How can I move a post to another topic in Google Groups?

Tags: google-groups

Is it possible to move a post posted under one topic in a Google Group to another topic in the same Google Group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to completely move a post from one topic to another. Also, as Google is currently not making advancements/improvements in Google Groups, it is highly unlikely to get the feature any time soon.

Anyhow, one workaround will be to post the same post under the new topic in the Google Group. If you own the Group or if the original post was posted by you, you will also be able to delete the first post in question.